# Sum cells with specific criteria of a column ignoring rows with other criteria in other column

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, excel-365

I'm having trouble figuring this out,
I have some criteria in column S that I sum in cells, whit those criteria I want to reduce the rows with the criteria "PC" in column R.

This code works, but it doesn't reduce the "PC"

```
Dim mycell As Range
Dim myrange As Range

Dim criteria1, criteria2, criteria3, criteria4, criteria5 As Variant

    Set mycell = Worksheets("mapa_cargas").Range("S2:S200")

    criteria1 = "PO"
    criteria2 = "DESCARREGA"
    criteria3 = "VAZIOS"
    criteria4 = "VASILHAME HNK"

    
    result = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(mycell, "*" & criteria1 & "*") _
    + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(mycell, "*" & criteria2 & "*") _
    + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(mycell, "*" & criteria3 & "*") _
    + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(mycell, "*" & criteria4 & "*") _
   
    
Worksheets("indicadores").Cells(4, 4).Value = result
```

[image]

The count with this code = 10, but I want to ignore the "PC" in column R resulting in 6.

Comment: Maybe after your result code lines, try to add : `PC_txt = Application.CountIfs(Range("R:R"), "PC", Range("S:S"), "<>")` ---> this should result 4 for the PC_txt value (based on your image sample). Then add `result = result - PC_txt`

Comment: unfortunately doens't work, returns 10

Comment: when you step run the code, what is the result of PC_txt in the Locals window ? Also, what is the use of "criteria5" in `dim criteria5 As Variant` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Sub CountPartialValues()
    Dim count As Long
    count = 0
    
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In Worksheets("mapa_cargas").Range("S2:S200")
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "DESCARREGA") > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, cell.Value, "VAZIOS") > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, cell.Value, "VASILHAME HNK") > 0 _
        Or InStr(1, cell.Value, "PO") > 0 Then
            If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> "PC" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Worksheets("indicadores").Cells(4, 4).Value = count
End Sub
```